# java - converting the data from table to an xml file

Tags: java, xml

I am querying the database. And trying to conert the data from a particular table and display that as an xml. I tried the following code, but still the xml is empty. I am still checking what is the problem. In mean time I am posting here. Can anyone please check and tell what is the problem?

```
response.setContentType("text/xml"); 

private void writeToXML(PrintWriter pw, ResultSet rs, Map<String, String> m)
      throws Exception {
    pw.print("<data>\n");
    rs.beforeFirst();
    while (rs.next()) {
      pw.print("\t<row>\n");
      ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
      int cols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

      for (int i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
        String name = metaData.getColumnName(i);
        String mappedValue = m.get(rs.getString(i));
        String value = mappedValue != null ? mappedValue : rs
            .getString(i);
        pw.print("\t\t<name>" + name + "</name><value>" + value
            + "</value>\n");
      }
      pw.print("\t</row>\n");

    }
    pw.print("</data>");

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

did you flush (and later, closed) the printWriter ?

```
pw.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting some exception. **PrintWriter** swallows exceptions.

Use **System.out** and see if the program is executing and if no then what exception you are getting.